# Create code coverage report starting at root folder

Tags: unit-testing, zend-framework, phpunit

I have just created a new zend framework application to try out unit testing.

I have followed [this](http://grover.open2space.com/content/unit-testing-zend-framework-111-and-phpunit) tutorial and everything seems to be working correctly for testing. There is a problem with the display of the coverage report. It displays the correct information, but the report starts at the root of my hard drive and I need to traverse the tree to my project folder to see useful information.

This means that every time I ran the tests, I need to click 5 folders deep to get to the actual report.

How do I make the report start in my project folder? This is my phpunit config file:

```
<phpunit bootstrap="./bootstrap.php">
    <testsuite name="Application Test Suite">
        <directory>./application</directory>
    </testsuite>
    <testsuite name="Library Test Suite">
        <directory>./library</directory>
    </testsuite>

    <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <directory>../../library/Zend</directory>
            <exclude>
                <directory suffix=".phtml">../application/</directory>
                <file>../application/Bootstrap.php</file>
                <file>../application/controllers/ErrorController.php</file>
            </exclude>          
        </whitelist>
    </filter>

    <logging>
        <log type="coverage-html" target="./log/report" charset="UTF-8" yui="true" 
             hightlight="true" lowupperbound="50" highlowerbound="80">
            <log type="testdox" target="./log/testdox.html">
            </log>
        </log>
    </logging>
</phpunit>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem...

I needed to explicitly specify my application folder in the whitelist. If it is empty, the code coverage report just starts from 'c:' and tries to find every '.php' file.

After adding the line in the whitelist section:

```
<directory>../application/</directory>
```

It works as expected.

Since I don't have any library tests in my test folder, including the Zend library folder probably had no effect and the report must have considered the whitelist empty. And because there is no blacklist, it just started from the root.

Answer (score 0):

The code coverage starts at the most common path for all files included in the report. So if your web root is in /var/www and you include libraries in /usr/local/zend/ the most common path will be the root path.

The solution would be to exclude the library path because usually you don't want to measure the code coverage for external libraries anyway.